# AWS Beanstalk missing configurations in console display

Tags: amazon-web-services, console, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-elb

The "Modify Load Balancer" page in the AWS console does not display any configurations. The only visible information on the page is the buttons "Continue" "Cancel" and "Apply." This page can be reached by selecting the Beanstalk Environment --> Configuration --> Edit on the load balancer configuration). I know the configurations are applied, because I can see them on the actual load balancer, and in the yaml file that I can generate from exporting the Environment's configurations. However, I have no way of viewing or modifying them through the console.

Note, this problem does not occur on all environments, just this particular one. The beanstalk application as well as the environment were provisioned using Terraform.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be because of a bug in the new Elastic beanstalk console (where some options or even some envs won't show ) that we are trying to fix currently. You can, however, get the details using the below command (change env and app name):

```
aws elasticbeanstalk describe-configuration-settings --environment-name myenv  --application-name myapp | jq .ConfigurationSettings[].OptionSettings | grep -i loadbalancer -B 1 -A2
```

Comment: Thanks for the update Ali! That's a good workaround for now. Please let me know if you make any progress on the console fixes, and if I can help with any additional information.

Comment: @Ali, I am missing the "worker" option in my configurations in elastic beanstalk. Is the issue still there? What command can I use to get my configuration settings?

Comment: Nevermind, my app type was web instead of worker